# Overlay over modal due transform-style: preserve-3d;

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, transform

I am testing this code, that works fine generally. However when i have a small screen if you open the modal, then we have the grey overlay over the modal. This problem is related to  `transform-style: preserve-3d;` I need to use this property, because my problem is much more complex. This demo is minimal but exemplify the problem.

So, basically I am trying to solve this bug but I can't find any way.

Issue:

```
/* Slide side body*/
    .side-body {
        ...
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
    .body-slide-in {
        ...
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c33mu5L2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c33mu5L2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply a 3D transform on the element in your case `<div class="side-body"></div>`, the `z-index` properties of elements inside the `<div class="side-body"></div>` can't be accounted for anymore so modal and it's backdrop `z-index` properties not taking effect as they suppose to when you invoke the modal.

**Solution 1** (recommended)

Remove Modal HTML from inside the `<div class="side-body"></div>` and put it outside and problem will be fixed.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c33mu5L2/2/)

**Solution 2**

If you don't want to put the Modal HTML outside the `<div class="side-body"></div>` (with your original approach) then add

```
.side-body {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d(0,0,0);
    transform-style: preserve-3d(0,0,0);
}
```

to `.side-body` selector and the elements inside `<div class="side-body"></div>` will not lost their `z-index` properties.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c33mu5L2/3/)

**Note:** in both above solution you can use `transform-style: preserve-3d;` but in 2nd solution there may be known bugs using `transform-style: preserve-3d;`, 2nd solution tested on latest version of Chrome, FireFox and IE but there may be issue on Safari (don't have Safari to test).